# How to show map with Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to show a Google Map, I have this code which does no work:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 240px;">Loading map, please wait...</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY_is_setup_correctly"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize(){
        var map_container = document.getElementById('map');
        var settings = {
            zoom: 7,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-18.893384076844953, -48.25330985812758),
        };
        var map = google.maps.Map(map_container, settings);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

When I refresh my page I see no map and JavaScript console throws me this message:

```
GET http://csi.gstatic.com/csi?v=2&s=mapsapi3&action=apiboot2&rt=main.102 [HTTP/1.1 204 No Content 428ms]
```

Why my code fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of the Map class.

Instead of:

```
var map = google.maps.Map(map_container, settings);
```

Write:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(map_container, settings);
```

Comment: Jeez, I was looking at this whole day and didn't see that :0 Thanks!

Comment: heh. error messages can be misleading sometimes. i compared your code with my boiler plate line by line and saw the missing "new"

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your code, you are missing `new` before the `google.maps.Map` constructor.   Your code should be:

```
function initialize() {
    var map_container = document.getElementById('map');
    var settings = {
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-18.893384076844953, -48.25330985812758)
    };
    // add "new" before google.maps.Map constructor
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_container, settings);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/8jdoknd7/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map_container = document.getElementById('map');
  var settings = {
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-18.893384076844953, -48.25330985812758)
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(map_container, settings);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 240px;">Loading map, please wait...</div>
```